# What to add in the requirements.txt for Heroku uploading

Tags: python, heroku, requirements.txt

I've been looking into the requirement.txt purpose through the Heroku website, but I've never understood what to truly add into that text file. I'm trying to host a bot using discord and the only thing I installed using `pip install ...` was selenium, discord. I understand it is the pip install package, but I see other people on youtube adding their git in it and such. Can someone help me understand this further so I can successfully upload a bot! Thank you!

Comment: Check this article out, [Heroku Python Dependencies via Pip](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting these in requirements.txt:

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
dnspython==1.16.0
PyNaCl==1.3.0
async-timeout==3.0.1
```

Also, make sure your txt file is named requirements (without .txt`)

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm. One thing was missing from me though, it was a selenium package requirement, but otherwise all of this was good. Thank you